# linking issue with x11 in C

Tags: c, linker, xcode4.3, x11

I'm trying to build a getPixelColor function using X11:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

void getPixelColor (Display *d, int x, int y, XColor *color)
{
    XImage *image;
    image = XGetImage (d, RootWindow (d, DefaultScreen (d)), x, y, 1, 1, AllPlanes,          
    XYPixmap);
    color->pixel = XGetPixel (image, 0, 0);
    XFree (image);
    XQueryColor (d, DefaultColormap(d, DefaultScreen (d)), color);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   return 0;
}
```

However I am getting the following error, seems like it's during linking:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_XGetImage", referenced from:
  _getPixelColor in main.o
  "_XFree", referenced from:
  _getPixelColor in main.o
  "_XQueryColor", referenced from:
  _getPixelColor in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea what the issue could be? I was under the impression that X11 wasn't a framework that I link as a library in my project - as long as I supply the correct header, then I should be fine... is this incorrect?

Comment: Are you linking to the X11 libraries on your linker line?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to link with xlib. This works for me:

```
09:25 tmp $ gcc test.cpp /usr/X11/lib/libX11.dylib 
09:26 tmp $ ./a.out 
09:26 tmp $
```

or with L switch and library path:

```
09:26 tmp $ gcc test.cpp -L/usr/X11/lib -lX11
09:30 tmp $ otool -L a.out 
a.out:
    /usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to link with compiled X11 libraries. The linker is complaining about object code not being found for the symbols being referenced. This is not a compiler error, so just including the correct headers will not be enough for completely building the executable.

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer? Not sure if it solves anything?

Comment: @AsheKetchum Yes it is the answer .. it's just not as helpful as any answer that shows how to link it in (say adding a path with e.g. `-L` and the library with `-l`).

Answer (score 0):

> is this incorrect?

Yes. X11 consists of both headers to keep the compiler happy, and libraries to actually implement the protocol.